Why are AAVs not a replacement for through-roof vent pipe?
I've read in many places online that AAVs (Air Admittance Valves) can be used for challenging situations (like an island sink) but that they are not meant to be a replacement for a through-roof vent pipe. Could somebody help me understand why it's not a good idea to put an AAV on your primary/only vent pipe?
Are there enough sewer gases to create pressure if they can't escape?
Asking because our house I bought has the vent pipe terminating in the attic rather than through the roof. Local advice I've gotten is to just put an AAV on it for now and in a few years put it through the roof the proper way when we replace the roof.
Think this will cause issues in the meantime?

Maybe because AAVs have a higher failure rate and need to be replaced.  A vent out the roof has almost 0 failure rate, but might need to clean out a blockage, but not often, if ever.

@crip659 that should be an answer.  It should be the answer.

Roof top vents are simple with no mechanical way to stop working.  Birds, squirrels, trees might cause a blockage that is easy to clean out.
AAVs are mechanical that have parts that fail/stick and need replacing.
AAVs are to allow air into the plumbing system.  They are not to allow the sewer gases out into the house.
Roof top vents allow gases to escape into the air, hopefully away from your or your neighbours noses.

It is my belief that an AAV is a solution to a problem.  It is not to be used as the only solution.  Best practices dictates that a vent through the roof is the best solution. It allows air to be drawn in and any gasses and noxious smells to be outside the home.
An AAV is like a "spacesaver" spare tire.  It can be used when you don't have any regular tire, but isn't the "best" solution.  (Ok, I know it's temporary as opposed to the AAV being used as permanent, but I hope you get the idea.)
As for using an AAV in your attic?  It is a temporary solution to keep the gasses and smells out, but not the best solution.  You can use it, but plan to get the vent through the roof ASAP.

Thanks for this helpful perspective. To continue with the metaphor, spare tires are temporary because they have the limitation of poor tread and are best used at low speeds. What's the equivalent limitation of the AAV? Is the downside/risk that they will malfunction and not allow air in?

The flavor of the metaphor was the AAV was not the best choice, but the only available  option at the time.  Yes the AAV will fail in time and not the best option for your attic, as well as a possible code violation.  However it is unlikely that an inspector will knock on your door and ask to see your attic. So given that you have the luxury of time to correct the problem using the best solution.

The vents connected at the bottom end of the pipe are needed to let trapped air out this is why there is vent stack from the bottom to the roof.
If you don't let that air out it will impede the flow of water.

Vents at the bottom end of a pipe would let water out.  Maybe you need to word this differently.
